# Watch for value change in macOS user defaults?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is it possible to access the system's user defaults values from an app?
Is there a way to watch for changes to a user default?

---

For example, let's say I want to know when the dock's autohide option changes.

From the command line I could poll `defaults read com.apple.dock autohide`, or maybe I could watch the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` file for changes.

But can this be done from an app? Is there an API for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, what does Firebase have to do with this?

Comment: According to [UserDefaults didChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1408206-didchangenotification) docs this may be possible with [key-value observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

Comment: @Fattie oh no problem, my fault for not getting it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @orhtej2 I know I can do that with my app's user defaults, what I want is to do it with the system's user defaults

Comment: this is a **great question** ..... I don't think there's a way to do it.  @NiñoScript can you tell us which settings in particular ?